Why does the React-Select npm package component not focus on the selected value when re-opening the dropdown options?
I am using the React-Select npm package component(v5.8.0) in my React Typescript app.  I am setting the value property as well as onChange etc.  When I select an option and the dropdown options close and I re-open the dropdown, the selected option is not focussed.  When you scroll down it indicates it is selected cause it is highlighted but it does not focus on open.
I can only provide limited code as this is company work.
<Select
                    options={publicationChange.map((x) => ({ label: x.Name, value: x.Id }))}
                    classNamePrefix="select"
                    onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                    autoFocus
                    value={publicationFilterId}
                    filterOption={createFilter(filterConfig)}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                        setPublicationFilterId(e);
                        
                    }}
                />

publicationFilterId is an object -> {label:"", value:""}
Removing the onChange and value props also did not have any effect.  Is this a version issue???
Removed the onChange and Value props, set value prop to indexes of selected value, used default value
